# Using sed how to replace a pattern if it occurs on a line following another pattern?

Tags: awk, sed

Say, the following is the content of a file

```
$ cat file
Name=Tom
Value=10
Name=Tom
Name=Harry
Value=20
```

On some occasion Value doesn't occur after a name. So what I need to do is find the Name=Tom pattern and replace value but only if occurs in the line immediately following the name. How to do that?

Comment: Does it *need* to be in `sed`? It might be possible, but `sed` is *really* not the best tool for something like this. Will solutions using other tools be OK?

Comment: Am I missing something here? doesn't something like `sed '/Name=Tom/ {n; s/10/11/}'` work for this case?

Comment: @steeldriver, that would fail on an input made of the 3 lines: `Name=Tom`, `Name=Tom`, `Value=10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More compact and somewhat easier:

```
sed 'G;/^Value=/s/=.*\nName=Tom/=42/;s/\n.*//;h' file
```

This appends the previous line from the hold space to each line. For `Value=` lines the value is replaced if `Name=Tom` was in the hold space. Otherwise the appended line is removed and the line is stored in the hold space for the next cycle.

Comment: Another proof that `sed` _is_ the right tool for this job.

Comment: Maybe faster: `sed -e 'N;/\(^Name=Tom\nValue=\).*/s//\142/;P;D' file`

Answer (score 5):

with `awk`:

```
awk 'prev ~ /^Name=(Tom|Anything)$/ && /^Value=/ {$0 = "Value=123"}
     {print; prev = $0}'
```

Or with the  *name* and new *value* stored in a variable:

```
export NAME=Tom VALUE=123
awk 'prev == "Name=" ENVIRON["NAME"] && /^Value=/ {
       $0 = "Value=" ENVIRON["VALUE"]
     }
     {print; prev = $0}'
```

With `sed`, the equivalent would be something like:

```
sed -e 'x;/^Name=Tom$/{g;/^Value/s/=.*/=123/;h;b' -e '}' -e g
```

Though, as usual, it's shorter but significantly less legible than with `awk`. Also, to work with arbitrary values stored in variables, `sed` doesn't have the equivalent of `awk`'s `ENVIRON`, or the ability to do simple string comparison (as opposed to regex matching), so you'd need to pre-process the values of the variables first unless you can guarantee the variables don't contain characters special to `sed`.

```
sed -e "x;/^Name=$NAME\$/{g;/^Value/s/=.*/=$VALUE/;h;b" -e '}' -e g
```

Would be a command injection vulnerability (at least with GNU `sed`) if `$NAME` and `$VALUE` are not tightly controlled.

Comment: Can we find a regex on the previous line using prev?

Comment: @DebabrataRoy, yes. Instead of `prev == "Name=Tom"`, use `prev ~ /regex/`

Comment: This replaces all values following Name=Tom. Including value after Name=Harry.

Comment: @DebabrataRoy, not sure what you mean. That answer is intended to replace the `Value` if the previous line matched a given pattern. If that's not what you want, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -e '
   /^Name=Tom$/!b
   $!N
   /\(\nValue\)=.*/s//\1=NEW_VALUE/
   P;D
' data.inp
```

## Explanation

- It will look for lines that have the name Tom in them. Non-matching will go to stdout.
- Then it will try to append the next line into the pattern space provided it's not the last line.
- Will look for the regex Value= in the line just appended and if yes then, the value is changed to NEW_VALUE (you should change it to whatever you require).
- P;D => will print the portion of pattern space to the left of \n, i.e., te prev line which had Name=Tom and then removes this portion. We are now left with Value=NEW_VALUE and with this it jumps to the beginning of the sed script line: /^Name=Tom$/!b Obviously this is gonna fail, and hence will be taken to the stdout. This is done to take care of consecutive Name=Tom lines.

## Results

```
Name=Tom
Value=NEW_VALUE
Name=Tom
Name=Harry
Value=20
```

Comment: You don't need branching here to take care of consecutive lines containing "Tom". Simply use a `N;P;D` cycle and attempt to substitute - if the pattern space doesn't match then nothing gets replaced anyway e.g. `sed '$!N;s/\(Name=Tom\nValue=\).*/\1NEW+VALUE/;P;D'`